# Which version of ubuntu is compatible with ACER Aspire 5732Z?

Tags: acer, aspire

I have an ACER Aspire 5732Z Laptop, and 6 days ago I have installed Ubuntu 11.10 on my laptop, But I found black screen in login. I have tried a lot of ways to solve this problem, but there is no way. So can you tell me which version is compatible with this ACER Aspire (5732Z)?

Detail: 
Intel-Pentium-processor T4400
(2.2 GHz, 800 MHz FSB), 
Intel-GMA 4500M, 
15.6" HD LCD, 
2GB Memory, 
320 GB HDD, 
Acer Nplify(TM) 802.11b/g/n.

Thank You.
..

And finally, I found that ***Linux Mint*** is best for my ACER-ASPIRE5732Z. It is also compatible with Ubuntu codes, because as I know it is base on Ubuntu.

Comment: Or, If anybody knows how to deal with this bug - Black Screen on ubuntu 11.10 - in my Acer Aspire 5732Z, please tell me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I can use the latest version of Ubuntu 11.10 by simply hitting the Fn+Left Arrow key after the logo disappears and I see the screen turn purple.

I have gotten used to doing this.  It feels like a security function now, so anyone who tries use it without my say so will get a black screen.

Comment: Yep, me too. I am using of this method. As you said it is good.

Answer (score 1):

according tho the article there is a bug in aspire laptops
go through this link
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1744809

reference [ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1744809)

Comment: This is not true. Ubuntu has always run perfectly on my Acer Aspire 5738.

Comment: yep, because of that I have asked to find that, if there is any compatible version with aspire laptops:)

Comment: @ Satchit Bhogle: Hey, which version of ubuntu are you using in your Acer Aspire 5738? Because I agree with pankaj sharma, that there is a bug in my Acer Aspire 5732Z. Black Screen. I don't know what to do? Should I use another version like 10.04 or earlier?? Any suggestion?!!